# Enlarging an Image when clicked - Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am developing a windows forms App as shown below. I want to capture screenshots, display them as thumbnails store in a picture box(dynamically) and add it to a FlowLayoutPanel just above the Add Control button. I've done this.

On top of the FlowLayoutPanel, I want the thumbnails to be enlarged and displayed when clicked on respective picture box control. Now I realized that I no longer can access the dynamically generated picture box anymore.

Can anyone help me in achieving it?

[image]

[image]

```
    namespace Snapper
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        static int imgCounter = 0;//keeps track of img for naming
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TestFlowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            CaptureScreen();
        }

        private void CaptureScreen()
        { 
            /*This method captures a snapshot of screen and 
             * adds it to the ImageFlowLayoutPanel
             */             

            Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bounds.Width,bounds.Height);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size); 
            imgCounter += 1;
            bmp.Save("snap" + imgCounter.ToString() + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            //creating a picturebox control and add it to the flowlayoutpanel
            PictureBox tempPictureBox = new PictureBox();                

            //generates a thumbnail image of specified size
            tempPictureBox.Image = bmp.GetThumbnailImage(100,100,
                                   new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback),
                                   IntPtr.Zero);
            tempPictureBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
            tempPictureBox.Click += new EventHandler(this.tempPictureBox_Click);                             
            ImageFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(tempPictureBox);

        }

        //This click event will be used to display the enlarged images
        private void tempPictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            PreviewPictureBox.Image = ((PictureBox)sender).Image;
        }
        public bool ThumbnailCallback()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is some updated code using a click event for the PictureBoxes:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static int imgCounter = 0;//keeps track of img for naming
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CaptureScreen();
        } 

        private void tempPictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Put code here
        }

        private void CaptureScreen()
        {
            /*This method captures a snapshot of screen and 
             * adds it to the ImageFlowLayoutPanel
             */

            Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
            imgCounter += 1;
            bmp.Save("snap" + imgCounter.ToString() + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            //creating a picturebox control and add it to the flowlayoutpanel
            PictureBox tempPictureBox = new PictureBox();

            //generates a thumbnail image of specified size
            tempPictureBox.Image = bmp.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100,
                               new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback),
                               IntPtr.Zero);
            tempPictureBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
            tempPictureBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.tempPictureBox_Click);
            tempPictureBox.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(tempPictureBox);

        }
        public bool ThumbnailCallback()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice I also took a little fun and made the picture box cursor a hand. You can change that if you want.

So to sum it up, just put the enlargement event in this:

```
private void tempPictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Put code here
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Wow. This is just what I'm looking for. Will try it in the evening and accept yours as correct once I've done it right. I would also like to add functionality to delete some snaps which are not required.

Answer (score 2):

You can access it on the `Click` event if you set it for your dynamically added pictureboxes:

`tempPictureBox.Click += new ...`

then in the `Click` method that visual studio will generate for you, you will have the `object sender` parameter.
You have to cast the `sender as PictureBox` and then you can access it.

Comment: Thanks, I've decided to include some additional functionlaity like removing some un-interested snapshots as well and thought the click event can no longer be accessed becuase tempPictureBox is being overwritten everytime a new picture box control is added. The below answer by SuperPrograman is what you've explained. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: You're welcome, happy this could help, good luck for the remaining work! (ps: you should mark as rasolved the @SuperPrograman's answer since it seems to address what you answered in an explicit way, mine lacks of details compared to his)

Comment: I've modified code according to your most important point casting as picturebox and now I could only get the thumbnail sizes and not the original size of image. I need a way to display the original image instead of thumbnail added to the picturebox of flowlayoutpanel